# How to add gender filed on profile, Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

I have created the column "gender" with type tinyint. 
Also at user model i have added the column at the fillable table.

But i have a problem, how to declare it on ProfileController, something like this

```
$gender = $user->gender;
$user->save();
```

Also after that i have made made a select form

```
{!! Form::select($user->gender', ['M'=>'Man','F'=>'Female'],null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

But i still cant achieve nothing, can anyone tell me where may have done the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a 'tinyint' type for the gender. And you are comparing it against character.

Change the gender type to string and then try again.

Comment: Stil i recive a error, Use of undefined constant gender - assumed 'gender'

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `select` field in the form using the following code:

```
{!!
    Form::select(
        'gender', // Name of the select element on form
        [true => 'Male', false => 'Female'],
        null',
        ['class' => 'form-control'])
!!}
```

When saving the user, you may use somethng like the following:

```
// Since you have declared a `$fillable` array
// with allowed fields so simply use create()
\App\User::create(\Request::all());
```

Check for male using:

```
if($user->gender) {
    // male
}
```

Check for female using:

```
if(!$user->gender) {
    // Female
}
```